# My Ubuntu Server uses the monitor only for error messages

Tags: server, keyboard, login

I have an Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS install that used to work fine.

Actually, it still works fine, but all I see on the monitor is error output, I can't login locally anymore, I have to remotely login via SSH.

99% of the times I login via SSH, but it still would be useful to login from the server room

So, the problem is this: **it only shows on the screen the kernel errors and nothing else**. No input from the keyboard, no login prompt.

The keyboard works, as the screen goes to standby and pressing any key will wake it.

How can I get the login prompt again?

Comment: Have you tried switching to another terminal, e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2? What was the result?

Comment: Ah! Somebody pressed Ctrl+Alt+F7 on the keyboard! (Who? Not big security but I should be the only one with the room keys) Switching to tty1 via Ctrl+Alt+F1 showed me the login prompt. Problem solved, thanks @Melebius!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may happen if the currently open virtual terminal is not configured well. Check if there is another terminal that is working:

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> or similar combination to switch the terminal. Valid terminals should be numbers 1 to 6 by default, so use keys <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>.